# Finding conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $Exp(1)$-distributed random variables. Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X + Y = c$ ($c$ is a positive constant).

this is my idea:

$$f_{X \mid X+Y}(x\mid c) = \frac{f_{X,X+Y}(x,c)}{f_{X+Y}(c) } $$

if this is the right definition then i might calculate the righthand side to obtain the distribution but Iam unsure

Comment: Since this is homework, you should include what you have tried up to this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\exp(1)$ random variables. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative with values in $[0,\infty).$

Use the transformation:

$$U = X\,\,,V = X+Y\\X = U\,\,,Y=V-U$$

The Jacobian is

$$J = \frac{ \partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}= 1$$

The joint density is:

$$ f_{UV}(u,v)=f_{XY}(X(u,v),Y(u,v))|J|= e^{-u}e^{-v}e^{u}=e^{-v}.$$

Since $X=U$ we have for $0 \leq x \leq v$ and  $0 \leq v < \infty$

$$ f_{XV}(x,v)=e^{-v}$$

and for $x > v$

$$ f_{XV}(x,v)=0.$$

The marginal distribution of $V$ is

$$f_{V}(v) = \int_{0}^{v}e^{-v}dx=ve^{-v}$$

The conditional density of $X$ given $X+Y= V = c$ is

$$f_{X|V}(x|c) = \frac{f_{XV}(x,c)}{f_V(c)}=\frac{e^{-c}}{ce^{-c}}=\frac1{c}.$$

So the conditional distribution is uniform on the interval $[0,c]$.

Comment: How do you calculate the Jacobian in this case?

Comment: Also, how would we extend this logic to the case where [$X,Y$ are standard i.i.d. Gaussians?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373422/conditional-distribution-of-x-given-xy-is-a-constant)?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees: $$J = \det \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial X}{\partial U}&\frac{\partial X}{\partial V} \\ \frac{\partial Y}{\partial U}&\frac{\partial Y}{\partial V} \end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\-1&1  \end{bmatrix} =1$$

Comment: For standard Gaussians you have $f_{XY}(X(u,v),Y(u,v)) = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-(v-u)^2/2}$