# Conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y$ is a constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $\exp(1)$- distributed random variables. Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X+Y = c$. ($c$ is a positive constant).

I have tried to solve this using convolution technique and change of variables but get stuck at the integration part. I think I'm over complicating this so I would love to see different approaches solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks. Ill do that on the future questions 

Comment: @SamSarwat You can edit this question to type using MathJax.

Comment: @SahibaArora Better?

Comment: Showing what you have tried is preferably to just saying stuff didn't work.  That way we can see what the trouble is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a convolution technique is the right approach.

Since $f_{X,X+Y}(x,c)~ {= ~ f_{X,Y}(x,c-x) \qquad~\,\text{by a Jacobian transform} \\ =f_X(x)f_Y(c-x)\qquad\text{by independence}}$

Therefore, $f_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid c) ~=~ \dfrac{f_X(x)f_Y(c-x)}{\int_\Bbb R f_X(s)f_Y(c-s)\operatorname d s}$

Which readily simplifies into the *pdf* of an easily recognised distribution.

Just substitute $f_X(w)=f_Y(w)=\mathsf e^{-w}\mathbf 1_{(0\leqslant w)}$ and *pay careful attention* to the support.

Comment: Can't we solve the problem without using integration? Since $X+Y=c$ is given we know that $X=c-Y$. Using the definition, i.e. $p_X(x)=\frac{F_X(x)}{dx}$, where $F_X(x)$ is the CDF, i.e. $F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)$ :

$$
F_X(x)=P(X \leq  x)=P(c-Y \leq  x)=P(c-x \leq  Y)\\
=1-P(Y \leq  c-x)=1-F_Y(c-x)
$$ 
Taking the derivative wrt $x$ gives $p_X(x)=\frac{F_X(x)}{dx}=p_Y(c-x)$. Since $p_Y(y)=e^{-y}$ is given,  $p_X(x)$ is found as $p_X(x)=e^{x-c}$, for $0<x<c$ and zero otherwise. Let me know if anything is wrong in my derivation.

Comment: @tempx No.  Indeed *under conditioning*, $F_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid c)= 1-F_{Y\mid X+Y}(c-x\mid c)$.  But you don't know either *conditional* CDF yet.

Comment: Differentiation only yields that $f_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid c)~=~f_{Y\mid X+Y}(c-x\mid c)$ and symmetry then reveals that $f_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid c)~=~f_{X\mid X+Y}(c-x\mid c)$.  We cannot just substitute marginal pdf for conditional pdf.

Comment: I couldn't get the idea @graham-kemp. But thinking is discrete domain, I understood your solution.

Comment: Thanks alot. The resulting distribution is the uniform distributopn (0,c)

Comment: @SamSarwat Indeed it is.