# Finding $E(e^X\mid X+Y=1)$ if $X,Y$ are independent exponential variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, exponential-distribution

> $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with distribution Exp(1).
>
> Let us define: $U=e^X\,,\, V=X+Y$. Calculate $E(U\mid\,V=1)$

I tried going by the definition and find the densities,but I always get a non-converging integral... thanks in advance.

Edit: the answer by the book is $e-1$.

Comment: I thought that too in the beginning but V=1 seems to limit the possibilities of X, its not 0 to inf

Comment: Since $X$ conditioned on $X+Y$ has a uniform distribution  (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879829/finding-conditional-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1), the expectation is simply $\int_0^1 e^x\,dx$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom - wow, that is a useful fact!  I didn't know that.  The referenced answer uses Jacobians.  Is there a less formal but more intuitive (esp. if geometric) reason behind it?  E.g. the discrete version (i.e. geometric r.v.) is also trivially true, so perhaps that's why the continuous version (exp r.v.) is also true?

Comment: @antkam That is one way to remember it. I don't know of any other intuition.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[U|V](v) &= \mathbb{E}[e^x|V](v)\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^x f_{X|V=v}(x)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^x \frac{f_{V|X}(v) f_X(x)}{f_V(v)}\,dx
\end{align}
$$

Note that $V\sim \text{Gamma}(2,1)$, so $f_V(v) = ve^{-v}$. Also (I'll let you derive this part)
$$
P(V\le v | X=x) = (1-e^{-(v-x)})\boldsymbol{1}(v\ge x).
$$
Therefore, by taking the derivative with respect to $v$,
$$
f_{V|X}(v) = e^{-(v-x)}\boldsymbol{1}(v\ge x).
$$
Substitute into the conditional expectation expression to get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[U|V](v) &= \int_0^\infty e^x \frac{1}{v} \boldsymbol{1}(v\ge x)\,dx\\
&= \frac{e^v-1}{v}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $\mathbb{E}[U|V=1] = \frac{e^1-1}{1} = e-1$, which matches your answer.

Technically the above only holds for nonnegative $v$, but we don't really need to worry about that, just wanted to mention it.