# Why is $\iint_{\varphi ^{-1}(U)}f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_Uf(\varphi ^{-1}(u,v)|\det \varphi ^{-1}(u,v)|dudv$ wrong here?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was reading Surb answer [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362174/a-question-about-mean-of-transformation/3362241#3362241), and I'm quite surprise that $$\iint_{U}f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{\varphi ^{-1}(U)}f(\varphi ^{-1}(u,v))|\det \varphi ^{-1}(u,v)|dudv,$$
fail here where $\varphi $ looks to be a diffeomorphism. So, it goes as follow :

Let $f(x,y)=e^{-x-y}$ defined on $[0,\infty )\times [0,\infty )$. Set $$\Phi(x,y)=(e^x,x+y).$$

Obviously it's $\mathcal C^1$, bijective $$[0,\infty )\times [0,\infty )\to [1,\infty )\times [0,\infty ),$$
and the reciprocal $$\Phi^{-1}(u,v)=(\ln(u), v-\ln(u)),$$ which is $\mathcal C^1$ as well.

Obviously $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=1$, using the substitution the fact that $|\det(\varphi ^{-1}(u,v))|=\frac{1}{u}$ $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x,y)dxdy$$ $$=\int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty f(\ln(u),v-\ln(u))\cdot \frac{1}{u}dudv$$ $$=\int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-v}}{u}dudv=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u}du=\infty .$$

What's the wrong thing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a mistake in that answer. If you set $\Phi(x,y) = (u,v) = \left( e^x, x + y \right)$ then $\Phi$ is a not a diffeomorphism from $(0,\infty) \times (0, \infty)$ onto $(1, \infty) \times (1, \infty)$! Indeed, if $0 < x < \infty$ then $1 < u < \infty$ but then
$$ v = x + y = \ln(u) + y $$ so $\ln (u) < v < \infty$. That is, $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism from $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$ onto the set
$$ D = \{ (u, v) \, | \, 1 < u < \infty, \ln(u) < v < \infty \}. $$

Then, performing Fubini, we get

$$ \iint_{(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)} e^{-x-y} \, dxdy = \iint_{D} \frac{e^{-v}}{u} \, du \, dv = \int_1^{\infty} \left( \int_{\ln(u)}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-v}}{u}\, dv \right) \, du = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2} \, du = 1$$

as wanted.